# CoreData: sort based on predicate/array using IN

Tags: sorting, core-data, nspredicate

I have a CoreData store and am looking to maintain a sort order as provided by a REST service. The objects in CoreData have a `guid` attribute and the REST-provided array (of GUIDs) is sorted. I would like to maintain this sort after fetching the objects from CoreData.

I am using the following `NSPredicate` in my fetch:

`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"guid IN %@", wishlistGUIDs];`

where wishlistGUIDs is the REST-provided array of GUIDs for the relevant objects.

Is there a way to fetch the results while maintaining the `wishlistGUIDs` order? I've explored using `NSSortDescriptor`, and assembling an insane sort descriptor array by iterating over `wishlistGUIDs`, but it seems overly complex and just "wrong."

Answer (score 0):

Can you limit yourself to iOS 5/Lion? This looks like a good use case for an ordered relationship (which comes out as an `NSOrderedSet`). You'd have a Core Data entity "wishlist", which would contain the ordered GUIDs.

Barring that, I think you'll have to do something ugly, like maintain your own sequence number for the list of GUIDs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the extra steps I took to resolve this same type of issue:

Defined the method:

```
NSInteger gidSort(Guild* num1, Guild* num2, void *context) {
    NSArray* wishlistGUIDs = (NSArray*)context;
    int v1 = [wishlistGUIDs indexOfObject:num1.guid];
    int v2 = [wishlistGUIDs indexOfObject:num2.guid];
    if (v1 < v2)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (v1 > v2)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else
        return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

Then after you get the results from the fetch:

```
NSArray* resorted = [results sortedArrayUsingFunction:gidSort context:wishlistGUIDs];
```